# Python Requests API 403 Error with same HTTP Request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to fetch an API using Python requests.

The API is documented here: https://consumerdatastandardsaustralia.github.io/standards/#get-data-holder-brands

The following request works on reqbin:
[image: screenshot]

I have the following Python code

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.cdr.gov.au/cdr-register/v1/energy/data-holders/brands/summary', headers={"x-v":"1"})
print(r.content)
```

This returns a 403 error, I'm not sure what other difference there could be between the two requests which could result in such an error.

```html
b'<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

I thought it could have to do with the Authorization header for the API which wants a RFC6750 token however that doesn't explain why the reqbin works without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `User-Agent` header:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0",
    "x-v": "1",
}

r = requests.get(
    "https://api.cdr.gov.au/cdr-register/v1/energy/data-holders/brands/summary",
    headers=headers,
)
print(r.content)
```

Prints:

```
b'{\r\n  "data": [\r\n    {\r\n      "dataHolderBrandId":

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a user agent. **Always** check the HTTP response.

The data in this case appears to be JSON.

Therefore:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "x-v": "1"
}

url = "https://api.cdr.gov.au/cdr-register/v1/energy/data-holders/brands/summary"

with requests.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
```